# Transformation for twisting a UIView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview, opengl-es, transform

Is there a way to use CATransform3D, or similar, to twist a UIView?  What I mean is to rotate the top edge of the view, but keep the bottom edge where it is. All the transformations I've looked at keep the view 'flat'.  Is this more of an Open GL task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need OpenGL. Here is a great tutorial from Jeff LaMarche to get your started: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-7_04.html